# Pyqt prevent combobox change value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcombobox

I have four combo-box boxes that in **PyQT4**. If user change the value in first combo-box the values from second are altered and similarly if the value in second combo-box change, that results in the change of thirds combo-box and the same case for the fourth combo-box. What i want is when i change the value i first combo-box it should result in change of only second combo-box while does not effect the changes in third and fourth combo-box. How can i do this in **PyQt** ?

I have **changedIndex** event setup on each combo-box.

Comment: Please provide the example of your code to understand you better.

Comment: Did you work my answer?. If it works, do not forget to mark it correctly and if not, let me know what you get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To prevent an object from issuing signals in a given context you must use [`blockSignals()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#blockSignals):

> **bool QObject.blockSignals (self, bool b)**
>
> If block is true, signals emitted by this object are blocked (i.e.,
>   emitting a signal will not invoke anything connected to it). If block
>   is false, no such blocking will occur.
>
> The return value is the previous value of signalsBlocked().
>
> Note that the destroyed() signal will be emitted even if the signals
>   for this object have been blocked.

To simplify the task, the `setCurrentIndex()` method will be overwritten.

```
class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def setCurrentIndex(self, ix):
        self.blockSignals(True)
        QComboBox.setCurrentIndex(self, ix)
        self.blockSignals(False)
```

The following example shows its use:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        l = [str(i) for i in range(5)]
        cb1 = ComboBox(self)
        cb1.addItems(l)

        cb2 = ComboBox(self)
        cb2.addItems(l)

        cb3 = ComboBox(self)
        cb3.addItems(l)

        cb4 = ComboBox(self)
        cb4.addItems(l)

        cb1.currentIndexChanged.connect(cb2.setCurrentIndex)
        cb2.currentIndexChanged.connect(cb3.setCurrentIndex)
        cb3.currentIndexChanged.connect(cb4.setCurrentIndex)

        self.layout().addWidget(cb1)
        self.layout().addWidget(cb2)
        self.layout().addWidget(cb3)
        self.layout().addWidget(cb4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot provide you exact code but conceptually you can set some flag at global level and when you don't want event to trigger you can simply return function call without at first line

Probably something like this

```
Boolean flag3rdCombo  = false;

function onchangesecondCombo(){

    if (flag3rdCombo){
        return;
    }

    .....

}
```

Comment: The question has as TAG python, it is not javascript.

Comment: Read my answer again. 
I clearly said i cannot provide you exact code but conceptually one can do this.Only a fool would expect such a thing

Comment: Again same thinking
Man this was to give concept
Do you understand what concept means ??

Comment: Anyhow
i dont have time to explain to you.